# Impedir Insert ou Update Caso data esteja em um intervalo Cadastrado

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, trigger

estou com a seguinte dúvida:

Tenho a tabela:

```
 Escala
 Data_Atuacao_Inicial, Data_Atuacao_Final, tipo
```

O *tipo* poder ser 1 ou 2

Quero criar uma trigger para impedir o *insert* ou *update* dessa tabela, se eu inserir uma escala ou editar uma existente e colocar uma data que esteja entre os limites de outra existente no banco impeça e retorne uma mensagem.

Exemplo:

```
Escala 
Data_Atuacao_Inicial = 09-10-2019
Data_Atuacao_Final   = 10-10-2019
tipo                 = 1
```

Quando eu tentar `inserir` ou `editar` um outra escala e colocar as datas entre *09-10-2019* e *10-10-2019* e ser do tipo 1 deve impedir(instead off) e dar uma menssagen (Já existe escala do tipo 1 atuando nessa data)

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: acho que a pergunta não tem relação com a tag c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua trigger faça esta verificação:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE inserted.DATA1 < DATA2)
   rollback tran
```

Ai para o seu problema, trate da maneira que for necessário a seguinte parte `DATA1 < DATA2`

Answer (score 1):

Tenta algo como

create trigger bloqueia_registro
on TABELA
for insert 
as
declare 
@codigo int,
@data date,
@tipo int 
select @codigo = codigo, @data = data, @tipo = tipo from inserted
IF (@data between '09-10-2019' and ' 09-10-2019' and @tipo = 1 )
BEGIN
delete from TABELA where codigo = @codigo and tipo = @tipo and data between '09-10-2019' and ' 09-10-2019'
raiserror('Já existe escala do tipo 1 atuando nessa data !',16,1)
END

Para fazer a mesma coisa só que com UPDATE é só mudar de insert para Update na declaração do tipo da Trigger " for update "